# Wrapping long HTML tags, which way?

Tags: html

Lets say I have the following html tag:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="myFunction(); mySecondFunction();" title="It's a button!"></button>
```

That gets pretty long and starts to be hard to read what attributes it has so I would like to wrap the tag by putting each attribute on a new line, but which way is a good practice to do this? Keep the `>` on the last attribute? Put the `>` on its own line?

Method 1:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
  onclick="myFunction(); mySecondFunction();" 
  title="It's a button!"
>
  Button Text
</button>
```

Method 2:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
  onclick="myFunction(); mySecondFunction();" 
  title="It's a button!">
  Button Text
</button>
```

Method 3:

```
<button 
type="button" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
onclick="myFunction(); mySecondFunction();" 
title="It's a button!">
  Button Text
</button>
```

Method 4 (only wrap when you get too long):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
onclick="myFunction(); mySecondFunction();" title="It's a button!">
  Button Text
</button>
```

Some other method??

I know anyway is technically acceptable, but keeping in mind how code editors manage tabbing and formatting, and just plain readability, would like to see what is the recommended way.

Comment: Code standards are opinion based thus.. This is off topic

Comment: I like the question, but i dont know the answer. [similar discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2204) - voting for option 1 :)

Comment: Voted to close because this is very much opinion based. Personally, as long as it's consistent, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

According to the line-wrapping section of Google's [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Line-Wrapping), It looks like method 2 would probably be your best choice. The guide recommends putting the `>` on the last attribute:

```
<md-progress-circular
  md-mode="indeterminate"
  class="md-accent"
  ng-show="ctrl.loading"
  md-diameter="35">
</md-progress-circular>
```

Comment: What would it look like if there is content between the tags like in the question `<a>Text</a>`?

Comment: It would probably look like the example from method 2 in the original post